# Google Wallet Integration In android getting 404 error while set currency as INR

Tags: android, android-pay

```
public static MaskedWalletRequest createMaskedWalletRequest(ItemInfo itemInfo) {

    // Build a List of all line items
    List<LineItem> lineItems = buildLineItems(itemInfo, true);

    // Calculate the cart total by iterating over the line items.
    String cartTotal = calculateCartTotal(lineItems);

    return MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()
            .setMerchantName(Constant.MERCHANT_NAME)
            .setPhoneNumberRequired(true)
            .setShippingAddressRequired(true)
          // .setCurrencyCode(Constant.CURRENCY_CODE_USD)
              .setCurrencyCode(Constant.CURRENCY_CODE_INR)
            .setEstimatedTotalPrice("10.00")
            // Create a Cart with the current line items. Provide all the information
            // available up to this point with estimates for shipping and tax included.
            .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
                    //.setCurrencyCode(Constant.CURRENCY_CODE_USD)
                                       .setCurrencyCode(Constant.CURRENCY_CODE_INR)
                    .setTotalPrice("10.00")
                    .setLineItems(lineItems)
                    .build())
            // Indicate whether we need the Wallet Objects associated with the user.
            .setShouldRetrieveWalletObjects(true)
            .build();
}
```

Here is my code getting 404 error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"Currently, InstantBuy does not support non-US transactions. The only valid value for currencyCode is CURRENCY_CODE_USD."_ see [here](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial#create_a_masked_wallet_request)

Comment: Well @EdSF, Thanks for reply. But when i have implemented InstantBuy in web, there "INR" is supporting.

Comment: Got it - I'm not a Googler -> [it says same for web](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/web/tutorial#create_a_masked_wallet_request_jwt) so perhaps you'll need direct Google support for your question. Hth..